# Oracle Exadata Error: CellCli not Found Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, exadata

I am trying to run cellcli on my one of the Exadata Cell Server. 
When I login to the Server, I am able to see all the files as expected. 
(Like: all_group     all_nodelist_group  cell_group      all_ib_group   etc)
When I issue command to start cellcli it gives me error that command not found:

```
# cellcli
-bash: cellcli: command not found
# which cellcli
which: no cellcli in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

Any idea what is the location of the cellclie executable on exadata?
Do I need to export any other path to get this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cellcli is in /opt/oracle/cell/cellsrv/bin. It should be put in path by /etc/profile.d/cell_env.sh

(from [Marc Fielding](http://twitter.com/pythianfielding))

Comment: This location does not exists on my Cell Server. 
Possibly CellCli is not installed I think. 
Any idea how can I install the CellCli on my server?

Comment: I think it is smarter to call your implementation partner.

Comment: Did the same. Got issue resolved. Insttalation went wrong somewhere. 
Now its Fine. Able to see fire the commnads. 
Thanks for the help.